# How to programmatically launch a specific home page in android

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher, homescreen

I want to be able to launch a specific page of the home screen in my app, is there any way to do this?

Below is the typical method to launch the home screen, but I don't see anything about add a screen page or index value.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the default Home screen.
Tucked away in the `Launcher` Activity source (at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/Launcher.java#822) is this chunk of code (see line 822):

```
if (!mWorkspace.isDefaultScreenShowing()) {
    mWorkspace.moveToDefaultScreen();
}
```

So it is not possible to specify the specific page.

Comment: Yeah, this is about what I thought from some other posts that I found afterwards. I would have to build my own launcher to add that simple feature. A workaround I thought of though was to change the default screen, is that possible? So far I haven't found any info on that either. But what I could do is change the default screen, launch home, and then set it back. A weak work-around but it would do what I wanted I think

Comment: Well, looking at http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/launcher/Workspace.java;h=2e04311f530003dbd76695f46876a785164acb99;hb=HEAD you'll notice that the default screen is hardwired: `mDefaultScreen = a.getInt(R.styleable.Workspace_defaultScreen, 1);` (see line 131). So you're probably out of luck as far as that goes. There is a `snapToScreen` method, but it is package-private and you would probably have a hell of a time figuring out how to send it a message. And yes, it would only work if the user isn't using a custom home screen app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to launch a specific "page" of the home screen. I wanted to answer this though because I think there's something you're not considering: a user might have a different app set as their home. For instance, I use the SlideScreen app as my home app, which does not have the different "pages" to it.

I would suggest looking for a different way to accomplish what you want, unless you're just going to use the app on your own device and don't feel that you're ever going to use a different app as your home.